# docker container does not seem to stay running

Tags: docker

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD ["bash"]
```

I ran

```
docker build -t myimage:mytag .

docker run myimage:mytag 

docker ps
```

No images are seen running. Why not?  How do I find more information on this, such as logs of why it exited?

Comment: Typically you'd build or install an application for the container to run, and set `CMD` to actually run that application; there's not very much interesting in a bare `ubuntu` image.

Answer (score 1):

you can see your container using `docker ps -a` with status Exited because your container started, it ran the command `bash` and the shell exits immediately. If you want to keep it running you need to use

`docker run -t -d myimage:mytag`

adding the -t flag will prevent the container from exiting when running in the background becacuse it allocates a pseudo-tty. For more info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: This was astonishingly helpful, I'm surprised this question/answer doesn't have a lot more upvotes!